# Windows 10/TexLive 2015 hangs during installation

Tags: installing, windows

I am installing TeXlive 2015 on a fresh Windows 10 but ran into a problem, I seek your help.

First of, my system:

> Windows 10 Education, 64 bits `install-tl-windows.exe`

after running `install-tl-windows.exe`, I choose a mirror that is within my country (Canada), changed the paper size, and changed the default path to:

`c:\chene\bin\texlive\2015`

and proceed with the installation. No other options were changed, I believe the download files were around 4.5GB or so.

The installation proceeded until the last step, where it hangs at:

```
running mktexlsr C:/chene/bin/texlive/2015/texmf-dist ...
writing fmtutil.cnf to C:/chene/bin/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
```

and it had been like for several hours.

I have tried to cancel it, re-install it with/without administrator privilege, changed the mirror, but it always hangs at the same place.

On the other hand, I've install TeXlive using the same setup on my personal laptop (windows 10/64bits) and everything went smoothly.

Any idea what may be wrong here?

I ran `install-tl-windows.bat` with admin privilege and got a more informed response:

```
running mktexlsr C:/chene/bin/texlive/2015/texmf-dist ...
mktexlsr: Updating C:/chene/bin/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/ls-R...
mktexlsr: Updated C:/chene/bin/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/ls-R.
mktexlsr: Done.
writing fmtutil.cnf to C:/chene/bin/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
Tk::Error: Unknown format directive fmttriggers=cm,hyphen-base,knuth-lib,plain, package aleph, execute AddFormat name=aleph engine=aleph options=*aleph.ini           fmttriggers=cm,hyphen-base,knuth-lib,plain at C:/Users/Elvis/Desktop/test/install-tl-20150826/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPOBJ.pm line 981.
TeXLive::TLPOBJ::fmtutil_cnf_lines at C:/Users/Elvis/Desktop/test/install-tl-20150826/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPOBJ.pm line 981
TeXLive::TLPDB::fmtutil_cnf_lines at C:/Users/Elvis/Desktop/test/install-tl-20150826/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm line 2152
TeXLive::TLUtils::create_fmtutil at C:/Users/Elvis/Desktop/test/install-tl-20150826/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm line 2821
main::do_postinst_stuff at C:\Users\Elvis\Desktop\test\install-tl-20150826\install-tl line 924
main::do_installation at C:\Users\Elvis\Desktop\test\install-tl-20150826\install-tl line 790
main::wizard_installation_window at C:/Users/Elvis/Desktop/test/install-tl-20150826/tlpkg/installer/install-menu-wizard.pl line 709
Tk callback for .button2
Tk::__ANON__ at C:\Users\Elvis\Desktop\test\install-tl-20150826\tlpkg\tlperl\lib/Tk.pm line 251
Tk::Button::butUp at C:\Users\Elvis\Desktop\test\install-tl-20150826\tlpkg\tlperl\lib/Tk/Button.pm line 175
<ButtonRelease-1>
(command bound to event)
```

Can anyone shed some light into this matter?

---

Edit #2:
I took the advice from http://www.tug.org/texlive/windows.html and ran the installation program in text mode:

```
install-tl-windows.bat -v -gui text
```

after an hour, I reached the following error message:

```
D:Effective TEXMFCNF: c:/chene/bin/texlive/2015/bin/win32;c:/chene/bin/texlive/2015/bin;c:/chene/bin/texlive/texmf-local/web2c;c:/chene/bin/texlive/2015;c:/chene/bin/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/web2c

running mktexlsr c:/chene/bin/texlive/2015/texmf-dist ...
mktexlsr: Updating c:/chene/bin/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/ls-R...
mktexlsr: Updated c:/chene/bin/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/ls-R.
mktexlsr: Done.
writing fmtutil.cnf to c:/chene/bin/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/web2c/fmtutil.cnf

Unknown format directive fmttriggers=cm,hyphen-base,knuth-lib,plain, package aleph, execute AddFormat name=aleph engine=aleph options=*aleph.ini           fmttriggers=cm,hyphen-base,knuth-lib,plain at c:/Users/Elvis/Desktop/test/install-tl-20150826/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPOBJ.pm line 981.
```

any help is very much appreciated,

Comment: Suggest to close, because it was just a user mistake, so we have no real question to work with.

Answer (score 1):

User error. It turned out that I was using an old installer instead of the one that is fresh downloaded from the internet. Once I used the new installer, the installation proceeded without any problems.

Comment: Congrats! You found the solution to your problem. Welcome to TeX.SX